# В чем разница между двумя решениями (Python)

Tags: python

Есть два решения, на мой взгляд, они оба правильные, может я что-то упускаю. Даже если во 2 решении в `if` поменять оператор `and` на оператор `<`, то решение перестает быть верным.

**1 решение:**

```
f = input()
s = input()
th = input()

if f < s and f < th:
    print(f)
elif s < f and s < th:
    print(s)
else:
    print(th)
```

**2 решение:**

```
f = input()
s = input()
th = input()

if f < s < th:
    print(f)
elif s < f and s < th:
    print(s)
else:
    print(th)
```

Задача [отсюда](https://education.yandex.ru/handbook/python).

**2.2 Условный оператор № I**

**Условие задачи**
[image: задача]

Comment: Второе неверное. Логическую ошибку предлагаю найти самостоятельно в качестве домашнего задания.

Comment: А если в ``s < f and s < th`` заменить ``and`` на ``<`` то получится полная ерунда.

Comment: я имел в виду оставить только оператор сравнения, `s < f < th`

Comment: Второе решение неверно, потому что выражение `f < s < th`, не дает гарантию, что th будет меньше f, я прав ?

Comment: @Эникейщик, а какая ошибка во втором решении?

Comment: @Grundy ну так ``f < s < th`` же

Comment: @Эникейщик, ну то есть то, что в ответах указано, да? Сначала показалось что речь именно про запись с тремя переменными

Answer (score 4):

- Выражение  `а < b  and  b < c`  значит вот что:

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

  **Тогда очередность всех элементов полностью определенна,** и мы можем вместо этого выражения спокойно использовать тоже
  `а < b < c`.
- Но в случае `a < b1  and  a < b2`
  (я намеренно здесь использовал `b1` и `b2`, а не `b` и `c`, чтобы подчеркнуть разницу),

  **очередность между `b1` и `b2` неопределенна** (`b1 < b2` или `b1 > b2`?):

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

  Потому мы **не можем писать ни**  `а < b1 < b2`, **ни**  `а < b2 < b1`.

  Но в этом случае **мы можем** вместо `a < b1  and  a < b2` применить `a < min(b1, b2)`.

Comment: если использовать `min`, можно все три переменные в него запустить и проверку вообще убрать :)

Answer (score 2):

В первом решении проверяется соотношение между целевой переменной (например `f`) и оставшимися

Во втором - указывается явный порядок для всех трех переменных `f < s < th:` - однако данное выражение будет неверно в случае `f < th < s:` - хотя `f` останется минимальным элементом.